# javafx communication between controller and main

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

Why does the following code always show `null` in the console when I want to get the controller ?

```
RenewCardFXML2_controller controller=loader.getController();
```

and the console prints `null` when i press the button.

I have two controllers and want to use textfield from the main app(membershipcards)-`txt_numberOfCard_GENERAL`  inside the second fxml file whick has its own controller.

`txt_numberOfCard_GENERAL.getText` command from seccond controller and use its value.

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package membershipcards;

import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import membershipcards.RenewCardFXML2_controller;

/**
 *
 * @author Primary
 */
public class mainGUIController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ImageView logoimg;
    @FXML
    private SplitPane splitMenuContent;
    @FXML
    private Button btnCards;
    @FXML
    private Button btnRenewCard;
    @FXML
    private Button bntNewClient;
    @FXML
    private Button btnEditCard;
    @FXML
    private Button btnStatistics;
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane detailsPane;
    @FXML
    private Button btnCardN;
    @FXML
    public TextField txt_numberOfCard_GENERAL;
    @FXML
    public TextField txt_memberName_GENERAL;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {


    }    

    @FXML
    private void loadCardsFXML1(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            detailsPane = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("CardsFXML1.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mainGUIController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        splitMenuContent.getItems().set(1, detailsPane);
    }

    @FXML
    private void loadRenewCardFXML2(ActionEvent event)throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        detailsPane = (AnchorPane) loader.load(getClass().getResource("RenewCardFXML2.fxml"));
        splitMenuContent.getItems().set(1, detailsPane);

        RenewCardFXML2_controller controller=loader.getController();

        controller.setMGC(this);

        System.out.println(controller);         
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't ask several questions in one topic. Your title is not related to questions. Read [ask] and then describe in details what is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`FXMLLoader.load(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-) method you are calling is a `static` method. Consequently, you have not called `load` on the `FXMLLoader` *instance* you created, and since that instance hasn't loaded the FXML, it has not initialized its `controller` field.

(A good IDE will give you a warning on your `loader.load(...)` line about calling a static method from a non-static context, or something similar. Eclipse, for example, says "The static method `load(URL)` should be accessed in a static way.")

The following will work:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("RenewCardFXML2.fxml"));
detailsPane = loader.load();
splitMenuContent.getItems().set(1, detailsPane);

RenewCardFXML2_controller controller=loader.getController();
```

Note that you can reduce the first two lines of that code block to a single line

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("RenewCardFXML2.fxml"));
detailsPane = loader.load();
```